# React & SASS - checkbox component not aligning with label

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am new to React and converting a previously pure HTML page into a component in React. How do I update the SASS stylesheet to resemble the previous HTML format?

This is what I currently have in React (checkbox is showing on right instead of left, and checkbox and labels are not aligned):

- [image]

This is what I previously had in HTML, and the ideal format:

- [image]

checkbox.component.jsx

```
import React from "react";

import './checkbox.styles.scss'

const Checkbox = ({ label, isSelected, onCheckboxChange }) => (
  <div className="form-check">
    <li>
    <label for={label}> {label} </label>
      <input 
        type="checkbox"
        name={label}
        id={label}
        value={label}
        checked={isSelected}
        onChange={onCheckboxChange}
      />
    </li>
  </div>
);

export default Checkbox;
```

checkbox.styles.scss

```
.form-check{


li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-align:left;
}
  label{
     cursor: pointer;    
  }
    
  label:hover{
      background-color:linen;
      text-decoration:underline;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First - you need to move the div inside the li - the only valid child element of a list is an li element.

If you wrap the input with the label you will get that alignment plust the added benefit of being able to click the lable to change the checkbox. Obvsiously I have replaced the React interpolation with static content.

```css
ul {list-style: none}

ul li {padding: 8px 0}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="form-check-1"
          id="form-check-1"
          value="1"
          checked=checked
        />
       $ - $0 - 50 </label>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="form-check-2"
          id="form-check-2"
          value="2"
        />
       $$ - $51 - 100</label>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="form-check-3"
          id="form-check-3"
          value="3"
        />
       $$$ - $101 - 150</label>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="form-check-4"
          id="form-check-4"
          value="4"
        />
       $$$$ - $150+</label>
     </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Also - since these options appear to be mutually exlusive - I would suggest a radio button group to be more appropriate - that way only one option at a time can be selected. Using checkboxes will allow multiple selections - which is probably not intended in this case.

The radio button approach (which I would recommend) - use the same name attribute for all instances of hte radio input.

```css
ul {list-style: none}

ul li {padding: 8px 0}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="radio"
          name="form-check"
          id="form-check-1"
          value="1"
          checked=checked
        />
       $ - $0 - 50 </label>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="radio"
          name="form-check"
          id="form-check-2"
          value="2"
        />
       $$ - $51 - 100</label>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="radio"
          name="form-check"
          id="form-check-3"
          value="3"
        />
       $$$ - $101 - 150</label>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div className="form-check">
      <label>
        <input 
          type="radio"
          name="form-check"
          id="form-check-4"
          value="4"
        />
       $$$$ - $150+</label>
     </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: The first recommended option hasn't changed the layout at all. I am intentionally getting multiple prices by using the checkboxes.